# Angular-ui-router: how to pass parameters to $state.get?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to get a state `todo-detail({id: id})`. I'm using `$state.get()`, but don't know, how to pass `{id: id}` arguments to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

State need be retrived by name. If you want to know params 'id' of state. Do this:

```
$state.get('todo-detail').params
// return {id:id}.
```

In other way you can get all states with

```
var arrayStates = $state.get();
```

then find states expected in this array

Comment: Sorry, my question contained a false assumption. I wanted to generate a hyperlink to a state, but parameters are applied to a state at the moment of hyperlink generation, not at the moment of state retrieval.